# Matlab custom colormap with only 3 colors

Tags: matlab, plot, color-mapping

just want to check if it is possible to make a custom colormap with only 3 colors? (there is no need for gradient).

Example: Data ranges from `0-100`,

- so `0-33` is one color,
- `34-67` is another color,
- and `68-100` is another color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a colormap with three rows. Each row defines a color in terms of R, G, B  components.

```
A = randi(100,16,16); %// example data
imagesc(A) %// display matrix as image
colormap([1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]) %// apply colormap
colorbar %// show color bar
```

[image]

This defines uniformly spaced thresholds between colors. If you need more control you need to have more than three rows, with some of the colors repeated. For example,

```
colormap([1 0 0; 1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1]) %// apply colormap
```

will define a 50% threshold for first color, 75% for second and 100% for third.

Answer (score 3):

Take this example:

```
% some matrix with integer values in the range [0,100]
Z = peaks;
Z(:) = round((Z(:)-min(Z(:))) ./ range(Z(:))*100);

% show as image (with scaled color mapping)
image(Z, 'CDataMapping','scaled')
caxis([0 100])    % set axes CLim property
colormap(eye(3))  % set figure Colormap property
colorbar          % show colorbar
```

Note that the colors are scaled to the range [0 100], that range is mapped to the current figure's colormap (which we set to only three colors).

[image: peaks]

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example: [How to create a custom colormap programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230837/how-to-create-a-custom-colormap-programatically/17232355#17232355) but instead of `R = linspace(0,t(1),50)'` you would use `R = ones(50,1)*t(1)`

or even simpler:

if colour 1 is `t1 = [r1, g1, b1]` etc then

```
map(1:34, :) = repmat(t1, 33, 1)
map(35:68, :) = repmat(t2, (67-34), 1)
```

etc...

OR

`map(1:34, :) = bsxfun(@times, t, ones(33,3))`
etc...

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488378/how-to-map-a-specific-value-into-rgb-color-code-in-matlab/24488819#24488819)

You can use that code and decide to interpolate between values or not, its just 2 lines of the code.

The result image shown in the original post for a GYR cutom colormap.

[image]